# how to cut fields of a directory name?

Tags: shell, string, cut

I have directory named `140905_M01771_0112_000000000-ABBYT`. I want to get the third field i.e. `0112`. I tried:

```
cut -d _ -f 3 131230_M01771_0032_000000000-A7874
```

giving me error:

```
cut: 131230_M01771_0032_000000000-A7874/: Is a directory
```

Comment: Cut wants to work on stdin, not a parameter ...

Answer (score 4):

When you pass an argument on the command line of `cut`, other than options, that's a file name to read data from. You're asking `cut` to process data from the file `131230_M01771_0032_000000000-A7874`, which causes an error because that's a directory, not a file containing data.

Instead of calling an external utility, you could use [the shell's built-in parameter expansion constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

```
dir="131230_M01771_0032_000000000-A7874"
third_field="${dir#*_}"; third_field="${third_field#*_}"; third_field="${third_field%%_*}"
echo "$third_field"
```

Answer (score 3):

As you know the name to operate on, why not taking it to a variable and pass the variable to `cut`'s STDIN, which you can do this way in bash, ksh or zsh:

```
% dir='140905_M01771_0112_000000000-ABBYT'          

% cut -d_ -f3 <<<"$dir"                   
0112
```

---

Or if you know the directory names will have at least three `_`s and one `-`, then a simple `for` construct over the names will do:

```
for dir in *_*_*_*-*; do cut -d_ -f3 <<<"$dir"; done
```

Comment: Note that strickly speaking, `cut -d _ -f3 <<< "$dir"` returns the 3rd field _of every line of_ `$dir` not the third field in `$dir` (which would make a different would `$dir` contain a newline character).

Answer (score 1):

The parameters to `cut` are the names of the files that contain the information to be cut, not the actual information.

If you don't pass any parameters other than the cutting definitions, it will look for the information to cut on its standard input.

So it makes more sense to pipe the information into the cut command. E.g.:

```
ls -1d -- *_*_*_* | cut -d _ -f 3
```

The given `ls` command will list all the files (including directories) with the given name pattern, and the list of files resulting from it will be cut by the `cut` command.

Comment: But be careful with parsing `ls`.

Comment: @Fiximan that warning usually applies to the result of `ls -l` or to anything that relies on spaces. It would take some exotic filenames to confuse `cut`.

Comment: It especially is a problem when the shell passes all unprintable characters with the same replacement. It's just a matter of "not making it a habit in the first place". Surely would not be a problem for OP, though.

Comment: It's also a problem e.g. when the file names contain non-ASCII characters that `ls` doesn't print through because the current locale doesn't match the locale used when naming the files. `printf '%s\n' *_*_*_* | cut …` would not have this defect or others, that would work for any file name except those containing newlines.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
dir=140905_M01771_0112_000000000-ABBYT
third_field=${${(s:_:)dir}[3]}
```

Or:

```
fields=(${(s:_:)dir})
third_field=$fields[3]
```

POSIXly:

```
IFS=_; set -o noglob
set -- $dir
third_field=$3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 140905_M01771_0112_000000000-ABBYT | cut -c 15,16,17,18
```